# WSL version 1 Unable to run ansible, module missing

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pip, ansible

I'm trying to run an Ansible playbook in Ubuntu 18.04.1 under version 1 of the Windows Subsystem for Linux (Windows 10 ver 10.0.18363.751), but I keep getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

I did `pip install jinja2` and it is installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.10)
```

I don't understand why it doesn't run. It seems like Ansible might not look in the right place for the module, but I'm not sure how else can I install it other than pip install...

Comment: @K7AAY thanks, done, I have verson 1, is that bad?

Comment: Don't know if it makes a different, just troubleshooting with tools at hand. Suggest you search here (see search bar in black above) and elsewhere for "WSL version1 Ansible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive upgraded to version 2 and its working now.